# Free-jqGrid – Button on caption click works only at center

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a free-jqGrid as shown below. It has a button with a `+` icon in it.

Expected Behavior:  On mouseover the color of the plus icon become white and on click, it shows an alert message.

But this functionality works only when the mouse is pointed towards the center of the button. If I move mouse from right edge of browser and reach the bottom right part of the button, no visual change happen – and on click nothing happens.  However if I do it on a simple dynamic button (without grid) as shown in second fiddle, it works correctly.

1. Button in Grid Caption: [Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/x59xx4n1/1/)
2. Dynamic Button alone: [Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/5Lzomg85/)

[image]

How to fix / workaround this in free-jqgrid?

Note: I am using **`Google Chrome`** version 58.

**Caption Script**

```
var htmlButtonElement = '<button id="btnAddProvider" type="button" class="btn btn-info toolbar-button" title="Add Provider" style="float:left;">'+
              '<span id="spanAddProvider" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="pointer-events: none;"></span>'+
          '</button>'


        function getGridCaption() {
            return "<div style='font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; display:inline; padding-left:10px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check' style='margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;'></span>" + getCurrentPractice() + " " + "</div>" +
            "<div style='float:right; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:10px; display:inline;>" +
           "<div style='float:right;width:550px;  padding-bottom:20px;'>" +
                 "<div class='btn-group' style='float:right; padding-top:1px;'> " +
                  htmlButtonElement+
                "</div>" +
                "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='filter' placeholder='Search'  style='width:250px; height:30px; float:right; ' />" +
            " </div>" +
            "</div><div class='ui-helper-clearfix'></div>";
        }
```

**Update**:

Fixed as per Oleg's answer: [Fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/rzjLa995/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your question more about jQuery UI CSS, which you use as about free jqGrid. The most elements of jQuery UI classes defines `background-image` additionally to `background-color`. To be exact, jQuery UI uses `background` to define `background-image`, `background-color` and some other `background-xxx` CSS properties at once. Thus you should use `background: silver` instead of `background-color: silver` or continue to use `background-color: silver`, but to add `background-image: none` additionally. You can additionally define `:hover` rules (like `.toolbar-button:hover`) to define CSS properties of the button in the hover state. For example, the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/x59xx4n1/3/ uses the following properties

```css
.toolbar-button {
    background-color: silver;
    background-image: none;
    color: darkblue;
}
.toolbar-button:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: yellow;
}
```

**UPDATED:** One more demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/x59xx4n1/5/ uses `hidegrid: false` option and remove `ui-jqgrid-caption` class from the header of the grid.

Comment: I checked your fiddle - there also the issue exists. When I move mouse from right bottom corner it is not highlighted. It works only when I reach near center of the button. The issue happens only when the button is on the grid. When I make a stand alone dynamic button it works perfectly (as in the second fiddle in question). Were you able to see this behavior using `Chrome`?

Comment: @Lijo: You use too many CSS styles on the elements, which you inserted in the title bar. You need analyse, which one have problems with other CSS properties. In any way the problem depends on CSS rules applied on `"ui-jqgrid-caption"` class used to position show/hide button, which will be seldom used. I suggest you to remove the button by using `hidegrid: false` option and remove `"ui-jqgrid-caption"` class finally. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/x59xx4n1/5/

Comment: Thanks. It works. Two requests. 1) Could you please update/replace the answer with this comment and fiddle? 2) Could you please elaborate why it fixes when `hidegrid: false` added and `ui-jqgrid-caption` removed?

Comment: @Lijo: I updated the answer. You can just remove `hidegrid: false` option in the demo, which has no `ui-jqgrid-caption` class in the title bar. You will see that the position of hide/show button will be absolutely wrong.